# How to do some action when Airflow Sensor times out

Tags: airflow

I would like to call a method when Airflow Sensor times out. Is there a hook provided by Airflow library to do such actions? I have looked into source code and it throws `AirflowSensorTimeoutException` once timeout happens.

Is there a way to catch above exception or some sort of hook provided by Sensor to some action post timeout?

Comment: Maybe use [`on_failure_callback`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L191)?

Comment: Which sensor do you use?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no easy option to do it for a specific kind of exception (in your case - timeout exception), you can achieve that by adding another task that does X and pass `trigger_rule='all_failed'` param to it, so this task will only run if the parent failed.

In example:

```
sensor = FileSensor(
    task_id='sensor',
    filepath='/usr/local/airflow/file',
    timeout=10,
    poke_interval=10,
    dag=dag
)

when_failed = BashOperator(
    task_id='creator',
    bash_command='touch /usr/local/airflow/file',
    trigger_rule='all_failed',
    dag=dag
)

sensor >> when_failed
```

You can also take this approach if you want to run only on timeout exception by using a `ShortCircuitOperator` with the trigger_rule that checks if the exception is timeout, but it will be more complicated.